# CakePHP: Manage development and production environment

Tags: cakephp, development-environment

I'm using cake php with an svn repository and i want to manage my app using
a development and production environment.

Is there a better way to do this than make 2 domain, 2 databases and merge files modified
from development to production?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create two svn repositories ...one for development purpose another for production.

And while doing that you can have the same database for both of them or it can be different (that actually depends upon your personal requirement) and you can have a different domain for the two..you can manage the domains by defining the absolute urls in core.php of cakephp and similarly manage the database connection with database.php and can make different database.php and core.php for respective environments. Once you are done with the development phase you can export the whole code into production environment and can change your core and database files